# Xamarin, Image View issue

Tags: android, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, imageview

Hi i'm a bit newbie in xamarin and i'm stuck in a problem with the imageview. My image is rectangular(1080x293) but in the Imageview appears to be squared with margin on the bottom and on the top, the image stays right in the middle! I want to align the image on top, tried with padding properties, set the width and height but nothing works! How can I set it on top?
Some help would be appreciated, thank you and sorry for the stupid question!
Here's a piece of code!

```
       <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/titleIMG"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0.0dp"/>
```

Comment: Can we see the full layout XML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got the same problem few days ago. I've just browsed throught the properties and found this one: "adjustViewBounds" which allows you to preserve the real ratio of your pic.
Just add this to your code:

`android:adjustViewBounds="true"`